# Service account application domain level API permissions

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I'm working on converting our app from oAuth1 to oAuth2. Our app uses drive access to populate  spreadsheets. The currently logged in user will post some data to a spreadsheet of another user on the domain. 
This worked fine using oAuth1 but now, when the service account tries to make a request on behalf of another user in the domain by setting the sub field in the `Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials` object, I get this error:

> Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
>     "error" : "access_denied",
>     "error_description" : "Requested scopes not allowed:...}'

The scopes are being requested like so:

> I found this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-php-client/WzI2YGeO-4I
>   and it worked if I log in as the admin and add the permissions for the service account client id.

**My question is, shouldn't that happen as part of the app installation process when the domain admin approves the access?**. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The scopes you are requesting must be included in your Google Apps Marketplace configuration:

https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing#configure_the_google_apps_marketplace_sdk

Additionally, make sure that your Service Account is created within the same Google Developer Console project as your listing.

Comment: I did that, but the only thing that seems to work is having the domain admin add those permissions to the "Manage API access panel". I can see my app there with it's permissions but until I add the same permission with the service account client id it won't work.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing everything correctly then. May be worth doing some sanity checking and make sure that you are using the correct keys and IDs there.

Comment: Does it makes sense that even though the app installation process is requested access to some scopes, that the domain admin then has to manually add them into the API access panel? Is it correct to setup the app as a service account rather than a webapp, if I want to be able to edit a document of a non-admin member of the domain without being logged in as him? This was working well with oAuth1 but since the change to oAuth2 I'm unable to act on behalf of a non admin user of the domain.

Comment: What you are doing sounds correct, and there shouldn't need to be a manual step to add those permissions. My guess is either that there is some small mistake or you've hit an edge case. Perhaps try building a test application that simplifies the problem.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with a Google App Engine/Java based app.  I've made sure that the scopes are correctly set in the Apps Marketplace config but the end customer is still required to explicitly enter the scope information in the Admin Panel > Security > 'Manage API Client Access' before my apps service account is granted access to the Directory API.  Was there ever any resolution to this?  Thank you!

Comment: Is the service account impersonating the domain admin, or trying to access the Directory API directly?